# Why are the titles of all questions on the Trilogy Sites not in the question format?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

They should be, to put the users in the Q&A mindset; instead of in the discussion mindset, which happens when the question titles are not in the question format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where they're not, people can (and do) edit them. It'd be a bit difficult to enforce this programmatically. Imagine if you got this error:

> Your title "format this date" is not a question.

Some users would just do this: "format this date?", which isn't any better.

The only solution to this is for users with sufficient reputation to edit questions which aren't titled as questions.

Answer (score 4):

Does it really matter? As long as people understand what you want, that's the most important aspect. The question can be in the body, I don't see a problem with that. Most discussions usually take place in the comments (if at all).